# how to get ajax data from mvc controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I want to get the value in my controller from ajax.  I set a break point in the controller and it breaks, but the value is not there.  Am I missing something in my code or do I need to change something?

Here is my controller code:

```
            [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SubmitResponse(string responseData)
    {
        string test = responseData;

        return View();

    }
```

here is my ajax code:

```
        $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 500,
            width: 900,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Submit": function () {

                    var response = $.trim($('#name').val());

                    //responseData = JSON.stringify(responseData);

                    alert('response data = ' + response + '!!!');
                    //alert('YES');
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'Questions/SubmitResponse',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: JSON.stringify(response),
                        dataType: 'json',
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        success: function(){
                            alert('success');
                        },
                        error: function(){
                            alert('error buddy');
                        }
                    });
                },
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the response data in the `success` callback.

**Edit**

I've prepared a full example in hopes to clear the confusion.
Let's say that in your client code you have something like this:

```
<button id="testButton" name="testButton">Simulate</button>
<script>
    $(function () {
        var dataToBeSend = {
            test: "This will be appended to the question title !"
        };

        $("#testButton").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Questions/Test",
                type: "post",
                data: JSON.stringify(dataToBeSend),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (question) {
                    alert(question.Title);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Oh noes");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Note: You can shorten this call by using [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

In your `QuestionsController`:

```
public class QuestionsController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Test(string test)
    {
        var question = new Question {Title = "What is the Matrix ? " + test};
        return Json(question);
    }
}

// Will be Serializing this class
public class Question
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Let me know if you need some clarifications on this.

Comment: I'm not seeing the data from the controller.  I'm trying to pass the string from ajax to the controller.